# how to add route in PATH on Slackware?

Tags: path, slackware, jdk

I have used this `export PATH = $ PATH:/usr/local/java/bin`
And when I use which java the path where java is found, but if I turn off my computer or close session when I put **which java** `/usr/local/java/bin` is no longer part of the PATH variable.